# From where hadoop gets PYTHONPATH variable value?

Tags: hadoop

I have installed multi node hadoop configuration. And I need to check whether hadoop is using the correct python or not. Indirectly i need to check where the hadoop job will look for python.

I will be using dumbo to run python code over Hadoop.

Comment: Hadoop uses java... What is running python?

Comment: I am sorry i did not get you. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Why do you need to check this? What part of Hadoop requires Python? Everything I know in the Hadoop Ecosystem is Java based

Comment: I will be using dumbo to run python code over Hadoop.

Comment: Okay. That uses the Streaming Mapreduce API running your python code through **Java**. So, you don't need a PYTHONPATH in Hadoop. The Streaming API is setup in a way that you read from standard in and write to standard out. It is language agnostic. Dumbo is just a wrapper around standard python code